# ssh host-based authentication on Fedora 35

Tags: ssh

I am trying to bypass password ask and use host based authentification.

Client is in shosts.equiv, client public key in ssh_known_hosts
and yet it forces to ask me password

Does it have to do with SELInux and PAM?

openssh-8.7p1-3.fc35 and openssh-server-8.7p1-3.fc35

**Server**

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts    
H,H.lan,H.lan.,192.168.1.86 ssh-rsa <Hpublickey1>
H,H.lan,H.lan.,192.168.1.86 ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 <Hpublickey2>
H,H.lan,H.lan.,192.168.1.86 ssh-ed25519 <Hpublickey3>
```

and

```
-rw-r-----. 1 root root /etc/ssh/shosts.equiv
H
H.lan
H.lan.
192.168.1.86
```

and

```
sshd -T | grep ^host
hostbasedauthentication yes
hostbasedusesnamefrompacketonly yes
hostbasedacceptedalgorithms ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
hostkeyalgorithms ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com
hostkey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
hostkey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
hostkey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
UsePAM yes
```

**Client : hostname = H**

a connection attempt forces password request

```
ssh server
user@server's password:
```

with debugging

```
ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=hostbased -vvv -E /tmp/s.log server
```

Here is the content of s.log

```
cat /tmp/s.log 
OpenSSH_8.7p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1l  FIPS 24 Aug 2021
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 55: Including file /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf depth 0
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf
debug2: checking match for 'final all' host server originally server
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf line 3: not matched 'final'
debug2: match not found
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf line 5: Including file /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config depth 1 (parse only)
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config
debug3: gss kex names ok: [gss-curve25519-sha256-,gss-nistp256-sha256-,gss-group14-sha256-,gss-group16-sha512-]
debug3: kex names ok: [curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512]
debug1: configuration requests final Match pass
debug1: re-parsing configuration
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 55: Including file /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf depth 0
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf
debug2: checking match for 'final all' host server originally server
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf line 3: matched 'final'
debug2: match found
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf line 5: Including file /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config depth 1
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config
debug3: gss kex names ok: [gss-curve25519-sha256-,gss-nistp256-sha256-,gss-group14-sha256-,gss-group16-sha512-]
debug3: kex names ok: [curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512]
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug2: resolving "server" port 22
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to server [192.168.1.66] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 4 IP_TOS 0x48
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.7
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.7
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_8.7 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to server:22 as 'user'
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:6
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 3 keys from server
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: have matching best-preference key type ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com, using HostkeyAlgorithms verbatim
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes256-gcm@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes256-gcm@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=32 dh_need=32
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=32 dh_need=32
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:Uy8VMmU9e9OnnoJWzLrojVNFaDk6LJiNR9asnFJy57g
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:6
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 3 keys from server
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host 'server' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,hostbased
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,hostbased
debug3: preferred hostbased
debug3: authmethod_lookup hostbased
debug3: remaining preferred: 
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
user@server: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,hostbased).
```

Comment: The client (`ssh`) code default for hostbased is off; unless turned on in a config file you didn't show us, try adding `-o HostBasedAuthentication=yes` (or `true`).

Comment: After reading here 
https://www.usenix.org/system/files/login/articles/09_singer.pdf and here https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/sysadmin/OpenSSHUseDNSErrorAnnoyance  this is the list of actions:   1. client side set HostbasedAuthentication to true for the target Hosts.  Set EnableSSHKeysign yes    Then on server side, set UseDNS to yes and have your client hosts in global shosts.equiv and their keys in ssh_known_hosts

Comment: On checking the source I agree EnableSSHKeysign is needed. UseDNS should not be needed since you have hostbasedusesnamefrompacketonly -- but shouldn't hurt either.